# Html: "-" is same as space" "?

Tags: html

In html, if I create a html table with column like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is your ID</td>
        <td>021-000-00001</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

space and - will cause multiple lines when it is rendered. 
So for space, the solution is:

```
<td>This&nbsp;is&nbsp;your&nbsp;ID</td>
```

but for dash sign -, even I replace it as —, like

```
<td>021&mdash;000&mdash;00001</td>
```

it still displays as multiple line.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">021-000-00001</td>
```

that should stop it breaking at the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML, one may use the numeric forms – or –; there is also an HTML entity –**

```
> In HTML, one may use the numeric forms &#8211; or &#x2013;; there is also an HTML entity &ndash;
```

edit : d' oh missunterstood the question :/